# How can I create 2 surfaceview which splitter up half of the screen on android?

Tags: android

How can I create 2 surfaceview which splitter up half of the screen on android?
e.g each of them takes up 1/2 of the screen.

I get this exception:
My app works when I do this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >
    <com.example.android.apis.graphics.Preview android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/view1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

as soon as I switch to this, even without using '@+id/view2', like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >
    <com.example.android.apis.graphics.Preview android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/view1" />


    <com.example.android.apis.graphics.Preview android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/view2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I get a NullPointer exception from this:

```
Choreographer.doCallbacks(int, long) line: 558  
Choreographer.doFrame(long, int) line: 525  
Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run() line: 711 
Handler.handleCallback(Message) line: 615   
Choreographer$FrameHandler(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 92   
Looper.loop() line: 137 
ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4921    
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 511  
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 1038 
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 805 
NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout android:layoutHeight="fill_parent"
              android:layoutWidth="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <SurfaceView1 android:layoutWidth="fill_parent"
                  android:layoutHeight="fill_parent"
                  android:layoutWeight="1" />
    <SurfaceView2 android:layoutWidth="fill_parent"
                  android:layoutHeight="fill_parent"
                  android:layoutWeight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The important parts are making them both equal in weight and both fill_parent.  To get around an odd bug in Android you may need to specify the layout has a width of 0dip.